# From socle of quotients to socle of ring itself

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, noncommutative-algebra, noncommutative-rings

Let $I_1, \dots , I_n$ be ideals of a ring $R$ with identity having zero intersection. Assume that  for some $x\in R$, $x+I_ i$  is an element of the right socle of $R/I_ i$, for each $ i=1,\dots , n$. My question: "Is it necessarily true that $x$ belongs to the right socle of $R$?"

I appreciate any cooperation in answering my question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There’s a natural injective module homomorphism 
$$R\to\bigoplus_iR/I_i$$
that takes $x$ into the semisimple submodule $\bigoplus_i\text{soc}(R/I_i)$, so the right ideal generated by $x$ is semisimple, and so $x\in\text{soc}(R)$.

Comment: It seems that the same solution holds for arbitrarily many ideals $I_k$.

Comment: @karparvar No, for infinitely many ideals the natural homomorphism is into the direct product, not the direct sum. If $R$ is the direct product of infinitely many copies of a field, and you take the kernels of projections onto the factors as your ideals, then that gives a counterexample.